# Python: Diamond Square Algorithm not working

Tags: python, algorithm

Im trying to make a diamond square algorithm in python with the help of [this article](http://jmecom.github.io/blog/2015/diamond-square/), but for some reason my current code only adds 2 more points to the matrix, and then it stops. Does anyone have an idea how i could fix this? Also, does someone know a link to an article which explains the diamond square algorithm for python?

Edit: the program doesnt result in an error, but it only runs the code which creates a new point twice instead of filling the entire matrix with points, in the resulting display the points are visible as red dots with black circles around them.

Code:

```
import random
from tkinter import *

#window setup
window=Tk()
window.title("diamondsquare")
window.configure(background="white")
window.resizable(False,False)
window.geometry("600x600")
disp=Canvas(window, width=800, height=580, bg="white")
disp.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)

def generatemap(size):
    size=2**size+1
    matrix=[[0 for x in range(size)] for y in range(size)]
    dummy=[[0 for x in range(size)] for y in range(size)]
    matrix[0][0]=random.randint(1,100)
    matrix[0][size-1]=random.randint(1,100)
    matrix[size-1][0]=random.randint(1,100)
    matrix[size-1][size-1]=random.randint(1,100)
    stepsize=size-1
    a=1
    while stepsize>1:
        halfstepsize=int(stepsize/2)
        for x in range(size):
            for y in range(size):
                try:
                    if matrix[y][x]!=0 and matrix[y+stepsize][x]!=0 and matrix[y][x+stepsize]!=0 and matrix[y+stepsize][x+stepsize]!=0 and matrix[y-halfstepsize][x+halfstepsize]==0:
                        avg=(matrix[y][x]+matrix[y+stepsize][x]+matrix[y][x+stepsize]+matrix[y+stepsize][x+stepsize])/4
                        r=random.randint(1,100/a)
                        dummy[y-halfstepsize][x+halfstepsize]=round(avg+r)
                except:
                    pass

        for x in range(size):
            for y in range(size):
                matrix[y][x]=matrix[y][x]+dummy[y][x]
        dummy=[[0 for x in range(size)] for y in range(size)]

        for x in range(size):
            for y in range(size):
                    count=0
                    check=1
                    try:
                        if matrix[y][x+halfstepsize]!=0:
                            count+=1
                            corner1=matrix[y][x+halfstepsize]
                    except:
                        corner1=0
                        check=0
                    try:
                        if matrix[y+halfstepsize][x]!=0:
                            count+=1
                            corner2=matrix[y+halfstepsize][x]
                    except:
                        corner2=0
                        check=0
                    try:
                        if matrix[y][x-halfstepsize]!=0:
                            count+=1
                            corner3=matrix[y][x-halfstepsize]
                    except:
                        corner3=0
                        check=0
                    try:
                        if matrix[y-halfstepsize][x]!=0:
                            count+=1
                            corner4=matrix[y-halfstepsize][x]
                    except:
                        corner4=0
                        check=0

                    if count>=3 and matrix[y][x]==0:
                        if check==0:
                            avg=(corner1+corner2+corner3+corner4)/3
                        if check==1:
                            avg=(corner1+corner2+corner3+corner4)/4
                        r=random.randint(1,100/a)
                        dummy[y][x]=avg+r

        for x in range(size):
            for y in range(size):
                matrix[y][x]=matrix[y][x]+dummy[y][x]
        dummy=[[0 for x in range(size)] for y in range(size)]

        stepsize/=2
        a*=2
    for x in range(size):
            for y in range(size):
                if matrix[y][x]>0:
                    disp.create_oval(50+x,50+y,50+x,50+y, fill="red", width=2)
                else:
                    disp.create_oval(50+x,50+y,50+x,50+y, fill="green", width=0)


generatemap(8)
```

Comment: Your linked article links to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm  ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You said *"and then it stops"* - please could you edit the question to be more specific? If it stops by throwing an error, post the full error message and stack trace. If it stops and returns incorrect results, show the actual result and explain how it differs from the expected result.

Comment: What exactly does not work. Error messsage / Stack trace? What is your wanted output what do you get, what did you do to debug your error and what is wrong?

Comment: I notice also that your code produces graphical output. It should be simpler to debug if you make it return the map as a 2-dimensional list of numbers, and then plot it separately in a different function. That will allow you to work out if the error is in the code generating the map, or the code plotting it.